# Multiplying independent conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If we know A and B are independent such that $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$, does $P(A|C)P(B|C)=P(A,B|C)$?

Intuitively, it seems like this should be true, but I don't know how to prove this formally.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Consider a chessboard and pick a square at random. Let A be "on an even-numbered row" and B be "on an even numbered column" and C be "the square is white".

A and B are independent, but $P(A|C)=P(B|C)=0.5$ and $P(A,B|C)=0$

Comment: Nice example (+1). Indeed, independence does not imply conditional independence.